# How do I customize how DataContract and DataMember names get serialized?

Tags: wcf, generics

I'm developing a WCF service, and one of the classes I am designing has a generic type.  It looks like this:

```
[DataContract(Name="RecordOf{0}")]
public class Record<T>{
   [DataMember(Name="First{0}"] T First {get;set;
   [DataMember] T Second {get;set;}
}
```

When clients generate their service reference, I want the record to appear as follows if I expose "DateTime?" as the generic type:

```
[DataContract]
public class RecordOfDateTime{
   [DataMember] DateTime? FirstDateTime {get;set;}
   [DataMember] DateTime? SecondDateTime {get;set;}
}
```

However, because DateTime is a struct, WCF serializes the first letter of the struct name as lowercase instead of uppercase (ie. like "dateTime" instead of "DateTime"). Also, apparently DataMember also doesn't care that there is a {0} in its name. What actually gets generated looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class RecordOfdateTime{
   [DataMember] DateTime? First0 {get;set;}
   [DataMember] DateTime? Second {get;set;}
}
```

How do I fix this? Additionally, is there a way to unit test how the data contract/data member names get serialized without having to generate a service reference?